# What is the official website for the Castel Sant'Angelo?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, italy, rome, architecture

I'm currently looking to go to the Castel Sant'Angelo soon as part of a trip to Rome. Unfortunately I've had some trouble finding the official website in order to book tickets to enter, as I've seen a number of websites advertising prices from €5 to €21, so clearly one of them is right and the others are scams or misleading...

What is the official website for the Castel Sant'Angelo in Rome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the official website for the Castel Sant'Angelo in Rome?

http://castelsantangelo.beniculturali.it/. Currently 404 but can look at some [mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20240304061952/http://castelsantangelo.beniculturali.it/).

Comment: Now it is working, but most browsers will complain that the content is not delivered with https. In any case, it say 16 euro, or 2 if you are an EU resident with less then 25 years